# Ruby Regex: Matching a < without a matching >

Tags: ruby, regex

Given the following XML

```
<Comment>10 < 100</Comment>
```

I want to be able to correctly Identify the inner `<` in order to be able to remove it, but I want to leave all other content intact.

I'm assuming this will involve some kind of [?] option, but I haven't managed to figure it out experimenting on rubular

Note: We are using an XML parser, rexml,  however it chokes on the above scenario. Conversely, Nokogiri chokes on an ampersand in the content.

Comment: Don't try to parse XML (or HTML or SGML or your favorite programming language or ...) using regexes.  It won't work.  Regular expressions can't deal with those languages. Generally, any time you have to match balanced delimiters (parentheses, brackets of any shape, XML tags), you have gone beyond the realm of what is possible with regular expressions.  Some languages have extended "regexes" with mechanisms to tie into the surrounding programming language in ways that let you do some of that, but you wind up with hackish, fragile code that is essentially a one-trick pony.  Use an XML parser.

Comment: Althought that's not valid XML, so is a compliant XML parser not supposed to bomb out?

Comment: We are using an xml parser. We are doing something kinda hackish because we are not in control of the xml, so in some edges where non-valid XML gets back to us, we need to be able to fix it as best as possible so our feature will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This finds and converts `<`s that are not followed by a `>`:

```
result = subject.gsub(/<(?![^<>]*>)/, '&lt;')
```

**Explanation:**

```
<        # Match a <
(?!      # only if the following regex can't match here:
 [^<>]*  # any number of characters except angle brackets
 >       # followed by a closing angle bracket.
)        # (End of negative lookahead assertion)
```

Comment: You're welcome. I always love it if people see "XML" and "regex" and immediately give the knee-jerk response "Use a parser, Luke", not getting the fact that parsers choke on the invalid "XML" you have to deal with. At least they refrained from linking to the unhelpful Cthulhu answer this time :)